# Syntax "Number.isFinite" don't work with Chutzpah

Tags: html, unit-testing, visual-studio-2015, chutzpah

It doesn't work to use syntax code "Number.isFinite" in relation to Chutzpah.

Is it supposed to be?

Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Chutzpah uses [PhantomJs](http://phantomjs.org/) for running the JS and the current version of Phantom does not support this. A new version (2.5) should be coming out soon and when it does I will update Chutzpah to this to resolve this issue.